# $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}=[v]_{\gamma}$ with $\beta=\{1\}$ a basis for $F$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ with basis $\gamma$ and let $v\in V$. Find a linear map $T:F \rightarrow V$ such that $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}=[v]_{\gamma}$, where $\beta = \{1\}$ is the basis for $F$.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't one be the transpose of the other?

Comment: @EuYu How do you mean?

Comment: Nevermind, I read $T$ as $V$ to $F$. I thought it was a linear functional.

Comment: @EuYu Yeah, I thought that too when I saw it first.

Comment: @EuYu Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What is the matrix representation of the linear mapping sending $1$ to $\mathbf{v}$?

Comment: $\beta = \{1\}$ is a _basis_ for the field. Every element $x$ in the field can be uniquely written as $x\cdot 1$. This is the field viewed over itself as a vector space.

Comment: Would $T:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $T(x)=cx, x,c\in \mathbb{R}$ work?

Comment: @Trancot Work for what?

Comment: As being such a linear map.

Comment: @Trancot You have to work with $V$ and $F$.

Comment: What does it mean to "find a linear map" like this?

Comment: @Trancot That could be an example. In your case, you have $V=F=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{v} = c$. But like Brian says, you need to show this for a general field $F$ and a general vector space $V$.

Comment: @Trancot We are given $V$ and $F$ and we must find a linear map $F \to V$ that satisfies the given conditions.  EuYu already tells you what it is.

Comment: I'm not following any of this. :-<

Comment: @Trancot I strongly suggest you go back and look at what it means to represent a linear map as a matrix. It's important to distinguish linear mappings from matrices, they are related concepts but not the same thing. A linear map "becomes" a matrix only after choosing basis. You seem to be confused on how this happens.

Comment: @EuYu Yes, see the image I uploaded just now in my post.

Comment: Do you see the first line under the definition? "Notice that the $j$th column of $A$ is simply $[T(\mathbf{u}_j)]_\gamma$." This will directly answer your question. You have only one vector in your basis $\beta$ which is $1$. Therefore the only column of your matrix is given by $[T(1)]_\gamma$. Since we need this to be $[\mathbf{v}]_\gamma$, it follows that we must have $T(1) = \mathbf{v}$. This _answers_ your question, but it's important for you to understand why this is. In particular, you need to reason out why the quoted line is true.